# form parameters sent but one of them received as nil in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The purpose of the **enroll** model is to group three other models **gymsite**, **user** and **role**.

```
class Gymsite
has_many :users

class User
has_many :roles, through: :assigments
has_many :assigments

class Assigment
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role

class Role
has many :assigments
has_many :users, through: :assigments
```

From the form at app/views/user/new.html.erb, input values are to be send to the app/controllers/user_controller.rb to perform the action 'enroll'. The problem is that all of the enroll_params are sent as is show in the browser, but at the controller, one of them become nil, in a recurrent way.

I have try by different means, including different form fields as select and check_boxes to try to solve this issue, with no result. I'm curios to learn what is the origin of the problem and how to solve it.Thanks

Browser processing information:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0z2B2t7H5wYJjtJMn8zBIPJ7sJaFk706EPh5JVZsC76x  GWeggrJi7RSxAu8GJJmsyrNP7NzVv6rNvmumNDyhsg==", "enroll"=>  {"user_first_name"=>"Lorena", "user_last_name"=>"Cueva",   "user_email"=>"lcueva@example.com", "user_password"=>"[FILTERED]",   "user_password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "gymsite_id"=>"1",   "u_rol"=>["", "2", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Enroll User"}
```

app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @enroll, url: users_path do |form| %>

<div class='row'>
<div class='columns medium-2'></div>
   <div class='columns medium-4'>
   <%= form.input :user_first_name %>
  <%= form.input :user_last_name %>
  <%= form.input :user_email %>
  <%= form.input :user_password %>
  <%= form.input :user_password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class='columns medium-4'>
```

```
  <%= form.input :u_rol, as: :check_boxes, collection: Role.all.pluck(:name, :id),  input_html: {multiple: true}%>

  <%= form.submit 'Enroll User'%>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

at app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def new
    @enroll = Enroll.new
    @roles = Role.all
  end

def create
   @enroll = Enroll.new(enroll_params)
   if @enroll.save
     redirect_to root_path
   else
     render :new
   end
 end

def enroll_params
      params.require(:enroll).permit(:user_email, :user_password, :user_password_confirmation, :gymsite_id, :u_rol, :user_first_name, :user_last_name)
end
```

at the app/models/enroll.rb all the parameters perform correct, except u_rol that becomes nil.

```
class Enroll
  include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :user_email, :user_password, :user_password_confirmation, :gymsite_id, :u_rol, :user_first_name, :user_last_name, :user, :role

     def save
       if valid?
         #find gymsite by gymsite_id
         gym = Gymsite.find(gymsite_id)
         #save user for a gymsite
         @user = gym.users.create(first_name: user_first_name, last_name: user_last_name, email: user_email, password: user_password, password_confirmation: user_password_confirmation )
         #assign roles to the user
           u_rol.each do |n|
            rol = Role.find(n)
            @user.roles << rol
          end
        end
    end
```

Comment: `u_rol` is an array in your params. You need to permit it differently than a 'regular' param. You should go back and read the guide.

Comment: @jvillian Permit it differently how? , where?. I assume what you mean is to treat u_rol different as an attr_accessor.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue changing enroll_parms to

```
 def enroll_params
      params.require(:enroll).permit(:user_first_name, :user_last_name,:user_email, :user_password, :user_password_confirmation, :gymsite_id, u_rol: [])
    end
```

in the app/views/users/new.html.erb, added 'include_hidden: 
false' to get rid of the blank value:

```
 <%= form.input :u_rol, as: :check_boxes, collection: Role.all.pluck(:name, :id), include_hidden: false, input_html: {multiple: true}%>
```

Now it works!. Thks @jvillian for the tip!